# How to show the department name in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following database design with repect to the Star schema:

```
alll table: ID, user_id, cat_id, qa_id
user table: user_id, name, department
category table: cat_id, cat_text, sub_cat_text
QA table: aq_id, q_id, answer_id
question table: q_id, q_text, sub_q_text
answer table: answer_id, text
```

I have to come up with a query that shows the total number of participants in each question including its subquesiont with all of its answers even if there is no participants in any one of these answers. Fortunately, I could be able to come up with a query that shows: question, sub-question, total number of participants in each answer. However, the problem now is with showing the department. If there is no participants in one of the answer, the department will be shown as NULL. So how to modify this?

My Query:

```
SELECT     dbo.question.q_text, dbo.question.sub_q_text, COUNT(dbo.[user].user_id) AS Expr1, dbo.answer.text, dbo.[user].department
FROM         dbo.alll INNER JOIN
                      dbo.category ON dbo.alll.cat_id = dbo.category.cat_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.QA ON dbo.alll.qa_id = dbo.QA.aq_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.[user] ON dbo.alll.user_id = dbo.[user].user_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.question ON dbo.QA.q_id = dbo.question.q_id RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.answer ON dbo.QA.answer_id = dbo.answer.answer_id
WHERE     (dbo.[user].department = 'pmod') AND (dbo.question.q_text = 'q1') OR
                      (dbo.[user].department IS NULL)
GROUP BY dbo.answer.text, dbo.question.q_text, dbo.question.sub_q_text, dbo.[user].department
```

Here is the Script of the database:

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [survey2]    Script Date: 05/22/2012 13:18:16 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [survey2] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'survey2', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\survey2.mdf' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'survey2_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\survey2_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [survey2].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET ARITHABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET  DISABLE_BROKER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET  READ_WRITE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET  MULTI_USER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM
GO
ALTER DATABASE [survey2] SET DB_CHAINING OFF
GO
USE [survey2]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[category]    Script Date: 05/22/2012 13:18:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[category](
    [cat_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cat_text] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [sub_cat_text] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_category] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [cat_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[answer]    Script Date: 05/22/2012 13:18:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[answer](
    [answer_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [text] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_answer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [answer_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[user]    Script Date: 05/22/2012 13:18:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user](
    [user_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [department] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_user] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [user_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[question]    Script Date: 05/22/2012 13:18:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[question](
    [q_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [q_text] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [sub_q_text] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_question] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [q_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[QA]    Script Date: 05/22/2012 13:18:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QA](
    [aq_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [q_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [answer_id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_QA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [aq_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[alll]    Script Date: 05/22/2012 13:18:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[alll](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [int] NULL,
    [cat_id] [int] NULL,
    [qa_id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_alll] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[showing number of participants in each Q]    Script Date: 05/22/2012 13:18:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[showing number of participants in each Q]
AS
SELECT     COUNT(dbo.question.q_id) AS Expr1, dbo.[user].department, dbo.category.cat_text, dbo.category.sub_cat_text, dbo.question.q_text
FROM         dbo.alll INNER JOIN
                      dbo.answer ON dbo.alll.answer_id = dbo.answer.answer_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.category ON dbo.alll.cat_id = dbo.category.cat_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.question ON dbo.alll.q_id = dbo.question.q_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.[user] ON dbo.alll.user_id = dbo.[user].user_id
GROUP BY dbo.[user].department, dbo.category.cat_text, dbo.category.sub_cat_text, dbo.question.q_text
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPane1', @value=N'[0E232FF0-B466-11cf-A24F-00AA00A3EFFF, 1.00]
Begin DesignProperties = 
   Begin PaneConfigurations = 
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 0
         NumPanes = 4
         Configuration = "(H (1[40] 4[20] 2[20] 3) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 1
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 4 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 2
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 2 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 3
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (4 [30] 2 [40] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 4
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [56] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 5
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (2 [66] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 6
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [50] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 7
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 8
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1[56] 4[18] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 9
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [75] 4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 10
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1[66] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 11
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [60] 2))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 12
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(H (1) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 13
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 14
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (2))"
      End
      ActivePaneConfig = 0
   End
   Begin DiagramPane = 
      Begin Origin = 
         Top = 0
         Left = 0
      End
      Begin Tables = 
         Begin Table = "alll"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 61
               Left = 226
               Bottom = 178
               Right = 386
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "answer"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 182
               Left = 0
               Bottom = 269
               Right = 160
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "category"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 36
               Left = 426
               Bottom = 138
               Right = 586
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "question"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 189
               Left = 427
               Bottom = 291
               Right = 587
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "user"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 45
               Left = 0
               Bottom = 147
               Right = 160
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
      End
   End
   Begin SQLPane = 
   End
   Begin DataPane = 
      Begin ParameterDefaults = ""
      End
      Begin ColumnWidths = 9
         Width = 284
         Width = 2265
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
      End
   End
   Begin CriteriaPane = 
      Begin ColumnWidths = 12
         Column = 1440
         Alias = 900
         Table' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'showing number of participants in each Q'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPane2', @value=N' = 1170
         Output = 720
         Append = 1400
         NewValue = 1170
         SortType = 1350
         SortOrder = 1410
         GroupBy = 1350
         Filter = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
      End
   End
End
' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'showing number of participants in each Q'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPaneCount', @value=2 , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'showing number of participants in each Q'
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_QA_answer]    Script Date: 05/22/2012 13:18:17 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QA]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_QA_answer] FOREIGN KEY([answer_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[answer] ([answer_id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QA] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_QA_answer]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_QA_question]    Script Date: 05/22/2012 13:18:17 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QA]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_QA_question] FOREIGN KEY([q_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[question] ([q_id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QA] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_QA_question]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_alll_category]    Script Date: 05/22/2012 13:18:17 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[alll]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_alll_category] FOREIGN KEY([cat_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[category] ([cat_id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[alll] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_alll_category]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_alll_QA]    Script Date: 05/22/2012 13:18:17 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[alll]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_alll_QA] FOREIGN KEY([qa_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[QA] ([aq_id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[alll] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_alll_QA]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_alll_user]    Script Date: 05/22/2012 13:18:17 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[alll]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_alll_user] FOREIGN KEY([user_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[user] ([user_id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[alll] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_alll_user]
GO
```

Comment: Your schema seems slightly odd to me: why separate QA and all? Why is category a property of all not the question? Why is user a property of all and not the answer? How do you you record which user asked a question (assuming you'd want to)? As it stands there's no way to show a non-null department for each question with no answers because you don't store one against the question - I'd guess you want the department of the user that asked the question?

Comment: first of all, the users will not ask or input any question.
second, I'm using a star scheme that means each table is per-filled with data except the ALL table which considered as central table.

I hope this answers your concerns ...

Comment: OK, fair enough - so this is a user survey you're building then with fixed questions and answers? I'd imagined something like StackOverflow Q&A where separating user and answer would leave denormalisation. I'm still not sure what department you expect though when there is no user participants on a given answer. Are you expecting to show all departments with a zero instead?

Comment: When the department is NULL what do you want to put instead? How do you know which value to put?

Comment: the query should show the result for each question based on the number of participants in each department.So, when the number of participants for certain answer is 0 I want it to repeat the department instead of showing null.

Answer (score 2):

This is a query *I think* you are looking for. It first cross-joins users and questions. Now that there are all possible combinations between the two you may start counting matching answers.

**EDIT:** changed join to answer to cross join to be able to count 0s.

```
SELECT 
       dbo.[user].department, 
       dbo.question.q_text, 
       dbo.question.sub_q_text, 
       dbo.answer.text, 
       COUNT(qa.answer_id) AS Users_Answered
  FROM [user]
 CROSS JOIN question
 CROSS JOIN answer
  LEFT JOIN alll
    ON [user].User_ID = alll.User_ID
  LEFT JOIN qa
    ON alll.qa_id = qa.aq_id
   AND question.q_id = qa.q_id
   AND qa.answer_id = answer.answer_id
 GROUP BY      
       dbo.[user].department, 
       dbo.question.q_text, 
       dbo.question.sub_q_text, 
       dbo.answer.text
 ORDER BY 1, 2
```

[You might check it @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c2b4/11).

[New version of query @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c2b4/13).

Comment: thanks Nikola,
but your query didn't reach my needs...
what I want for instance is to retrieve question 1 and all its sub-questions AND for each question/sub-question I want the following:
number of users of answers strongly agree
number of users of answers agree
number of users of answers strongly disagree
number of users of answers disagree
number of users of answers don't know
FOR CERTAIN DEPARTMENT...

I hope now its clear...

Comment: @Kemoid Could you please post some sample data and expected results to avoid guesswork?

Comment: I attached the script of my DB you can look at it.
and a sample output that I want is a table with the following columns:
    question_text, Sub-question_text, answer, number_of_participants, department
e.g. q1, sub_q1, strongly agree, 3, department1
e.g. q1, sub_q1, strongly disagree, 1, department1
e.g. q1, sub_q1, agree, 3, department1
e.g. q1, sub_q1, disagree, 0, department1
e.g. q1, sub_q2, strongly agree, 3, department1
e.g. q1, sub_q2, strongly disagree, 1, department1
e.g. q1, sub_q2, agree, 0, department1
e.g. q1, sub_q2, disagree, 4, department1

and so on....

Comment: @Kemoid It seems to me that you want to be able to display ALL answers, including missing ones. You might employ another cross join to do that; please check my revised answer. And, if this is not what you need, please put some **data** together along with expected results.

Comment: @Kemoid You might add data to tables I've created at Sql Fiddle - see link above. If you do, post the link back because each change of data produces new url.